# Most recent questions filtered by tags and country

Tags: support, data-explorer, tag-search

Would you assist in composing a Data Explorer query returning the top 100 most recent questions filtered by both tags and user country?

Answer (score 5):

[Here you go](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/990959/most-recent-questions-filtered-by-tags-and-country?TagName=javascript&Location=USA), it's not too hard. Please take a moment to read the awesome [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) so that you'll be able to build queries like this yourself. There's also a [dedicated chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede) for help with SEDE queries.

[image]

Comment: I will just add that since some users might include just city, or city and state (and not country) in the location field in their profile, it is possible to play around a bit more with queries like this - if somebody feels like doing that. For example, I have seen [this query for users from Ukraine](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/157038/user-list-top-n-ukraine-with-false-positive-exclusions?Top=200).